# The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: scala

When I start play **scala** production mode that throw this kind of error please any one give me the clear idea..

```
F:\New_CMS\trunk\server\cms>activator start
[info] Loading project definition from F:\New_CMS\trunk\server\cms\project
[info] Set current project to cms (in build file:/F:/New_CMS/trunk/server/cms/)
[info] Wrote F:\New_CMS\trunk\server\cms\target\scala-2.11\cms_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps as a Windows solution:

1. `activator stage` in the command line
2. Copy the stage directory from `target\universal\stage` to `c:\stage` to avoid issues with long file paths
3. To avoid the Bad Application Path issues just create a new `.bat` file with the following (my project is called proj): `set PROJ_OPTS="-Dconfig.file=../conf/application.conf" proj.bat`

Note: change `PROJ_OPTS` to `YOURPROJECTNAME_OPTS` and `proj.bat` to `yourprojectname.bat`