# Scala REPL from cmd: The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: windows, scala, cmd

My Scala (2.12) REPL recently stopped working.  When starting it from cmd it tells me `the syntax of the command is incorrect`.  The only system changes I can think of were installing IntelliJ 2016.2 (which I've tried uninstalling and no luck) and "Cmder" (http://cmder.net/) mini version which is standalone and shouldn't have changed anything. There could have been windows updates.  I've tried uninstalling Scala (had 2.12.0-M3) and installing Scala 2.12.0-M5, and it didn't work.  I uninstalled 2.12 have installed 2.11.8 and it's REPL seems to work fine.  So perhaps it's a bug with Scala.  I may log an issue to them later if there's nothing to go on here.

The closest thing I found to my problem is: [The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956257/the-input-line-is-too-long-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect), but I'm not trying to start an activator project, just the REPL from command line.

These steps I performed (while 2.12 was installed):

I tried setting Java 6 as JAVA_HOME:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/tools/nsc/MainGenericRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

which makes since as Java 8 is the minimum, so at least it tries to start a java process and is picking up that environment variable.

when I have Java 8 as JAVA_HOME I get:
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

```
C:\Users\tombstone>scala " "
]==[-toolcp] was unexpected at this time.
```

any other arguments (including `-version`) I tried give me the syntax is incorrect

```
C:\Users\tombstone>where scala
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin\scala
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin\scala.bat
```

which seems correct to me

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I debugged this problem by turning `echo on` in the scala.bat file.  Then I found that my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable had an extra quotation mark at the end due to one of my other scripts calling `setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\"`, the extra `\` made it get treated as a literal quote and placed in my environment variable.  When the scala.bat file checked my `JAVA_HOME`, it got the invalid syntax error due to it having an extra quotation mark.